# Hadoop 3.2 Oozie -Pig issue

Tags: java, hadoop, guava, oozie, hadoop3

I am using Hadoop 3.2.1 with pig 0.17.0 and oozie 5.1.0. While Ensuring the Pig Workflow sample in 
    Oozie I have encountered an issue in oozie which are mentioned below.

I currently using Guava jar 20.0  but I have changed the guava jar `versions(27.0,14.02,11.0) share/lib/ directory` and `local directory` but I got the same issue.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.io.Closeables.closeQuietly(Ljava/io/Closeable;)V
at org.apache.pig.Main.log4jConfAsProperties(Main.java:826)
at org.apache.pig.Main.configureLog4J(Main.java:769)
at org.apache.pig.Main.run(Main.java:409)
at org.apache.pig.PigRunner.run(PigRunner.java:49)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.logExpandedScript(PigMain.java:244)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.run(PigMain.java:199)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.LauncherMain.run(LauncherMain.java:104)
at org.apache.oozie.action.hadoop.PigMain.main(PigMain.java:77)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
```

Comment: Please describe what you have done so far in order to solve the problem.

Comment: i Have changed versions of guava jar but still show same issue

Comment: I fixed the grammar mistakes. Improved the title and tags. Removed extra words.

Comment: Are these jars placed in HDFS as well, where the oozie shared lib path is set? If yes, has this path been mentioned in the job.properties file? Even if that does not work, try placing this jar inside the <job>/lib directory of the workflow in HDFS.